# MethodNotAllowedHttpException on resource defined method Laravel-4

Tags: php, methods, laravel-4

I created a very simple form so that I could use a submit button rather than a link to open up an edit users page. Using a link works perfectly, but the form button fails and yields a MethodNotAllowedHttpException even though the method ("edit") is perfectly defined in the UsersController resource and otherwise works fine.

Route:

```
Route::resource('users','UsersController');
```

UsersController:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = $this->user->find($id);
        return View::make('users.edit')->with('user',$user);
    }
```

show.blade.php:

```
<!-- This works fine: -->
{{ link_to_route('users.edit', ("Edit: " .$user->first_name." ".$user->last_name), $user->id) }}

<!-- This doesn't work, and yields the Method Not Allowed exception: -->
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('users.edit',$user->id))) }}
{{ Form::submit('Edit User', array('class'=>'button')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mitch, no -- I added a comment (below) to your reply briefly explaining why the answer didn't work. In more detail: The issue isn't the routing -- I *am* trying to go to the users/edit page where I have the form to update the user. The {{ Form::open... }} is NOT on the edit page, it's simply on a display page. For comparison, right above the form is a link that works perfectly to go to the users/edit page. I'm simply trying to replace that link with the form so that I can use a form button rather than a link, and I don't understand why that doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Okay well you are getting the error Method Not Allowed Exception because you are pointing your `Form::open()` method to `users.edit` that is not allowed because you could never submit a form to the `users.edit` route. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, so I cannot help you further, but now you know why you are receiving the error.

Comment: I'm simply trying to use a form for route navigation, rather than using a link. In other words, a person can click a button rather than a link. I suppose I can simply use an image to do the same thing. But using a form for this purpose works perfectly with plain old PHP, so I don't understand why I can't do it with Laravel. Sorry, I'm not trying to be difficult, I'm just trying to figure out Laravel. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Form::open()`, it defaults to using the `post` request method. But when you create a `Route::resource()`, the `edit` method takes a `get` request.

To make it work through the form, you'll need to open it with an additional parameter, like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('users.edit',$user->id),
   'method' => 'get')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to the update route, not edit.

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('users.update', $user->id))) }}
```

The edit route is for displaying the view, while the update is for the put/patch request.

For more information about using the RESTful routes, I'd recommend checking out http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but, no, I am trying to point to the edit route, not the update root. I am routing from a page that prints information about a user (users/show) to the page that allows that user to be edited (users/edit), exactly the same as I did in the link just above the form. I put them both there for comparison -- the target route is the same.