# Laravel Route resource MethodNotAllowedHttpException on destroy method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am using a **resource Laravel route** defined by the following line in my routes.php :

```
Route::resource('test', 'App\Controllers\Teacher\TestController', ['only' => ['index', 'create', 'destroy']]);
```

The **index method works fine**. In the template of index I have created a form in order to remove an item of the list.

```
<form method="DELETE" action="{{ URL::action('App\Controllers\Teacher\TestController@destroy', $audit->id ) }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Remove" />
</form>
```

The URL is correctly generated by Laravel but **when I post this form** I get the following error :

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException' in /var/www/project/bootstrap/compiled.php:5365
```

I have already **try to change DELETE by POST** in the method attribute of my form but it doesn't work.

I also read this post but it doesn't help me : [MethodNotAllowedHttpException on resource defined method Laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459569/methodnotallowedhttpexception-on-resource-defined-method-laravel-4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you manually create your form you should use `POST` as method, and use `_method` input with `delete` value this way:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ URL::action('App\Controllers\Teacher\TestController@destroy', $audit->id ) }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
    <input type="submit" value="Remove" />
</form>
```

[Reference in Laravel documentation for form method spoofing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing)

Comment: A big thank you. I don't found any mention of that in the documentation !

Comment: @jedema I've updated my answer with link to documentation (it's for Laravel 5.1 but the same is for Laravel 4)

Comment: Thanks for the doc link :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="/test" ....>
```

Comment: What exactly should be tried? Why should the OP use a fixed URL rather than one generated by the router?